What are the benefits of TargetDevice -> "CoreML"
I thought this would be supported in 14.1 on MacOS:
trained = 
 NetTrain[LinearLayer[], {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1}, 
  TargetDevice -> "CoreML"]

(* NetTrain::trgdevbad: Invalid setting TargetDevice -> CoreML. *)

What can we expect in terms of speedup on apple silicon (like 3x-ish?) and what are the memory limitations?

I'm having the same issue. The ref page for TargetDevice suggests running PacletInstall["MXNetResources"], yet that throws an error saying the paclet cannot be found.

Reading the v14.1 blog post: ... the result is typically 2x to 10x faster performance.

Omg they forgot to support training it looks like!!

@GregHurst Somehow I get an impression that the feature was postponed from 14.1 to 14.2 but they forgot to update the documentation to reflect that. Or maybe they manage to push a paclet hotfix for this, but nonetheless, it's annoying...

@M.R. WRI confirmed that "CoreML" works only with inference (for now?). Clarifying documentation has been suggested internally, I've learnt. Training and inference can be quite different tasks and having actual support for training on a new architecture probably involves quite a bit of work.
